# How to emit data to specific group of users using socket.io from node server to react frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm working with socket.io and node.js trying to make a near real time IoT dashboard and until now it seems pretty good, but I don't know how to send a message from the server to an specific group which has n number of users in it, for example:

One site named "abc" has 20 users in it and another site named "xyz" has 30 users in it, I want to emit the data of respective sites to the users in it. There can be a situation where a user can be in both the site "abc" & "xyz" at the same time, I want to send data to all the connected clients (there will not be any message sent from the frontend to the server).

[image]

Here is how it looks like sites and users relationship.

Any help with respect to how can i acheive this functionality will be greatly helpful. Thanks